# Android start CALL (NOT DIAL) in nexus

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

**Please read before considering it duplicate or suggesting to dial!**

I've added proper permission to my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And this is how I'm trying to start a call:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123123"));
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

This variation makes no difference:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123123"));
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

I DO NOT WANT TO SHOW DIALLER, I need to START A CALL.

The problem is: Nexus is not starting the call. It's opening the dialer displaying the number I passed in the intent.

How can I change this behavior? Can I predict if the call will be started?

**EDIT**
The number that I'll call is an emergency number, but this problem happens with regular numbers as well.

**EDIT 2** It seems the problem I'm having is because I'm trying to make a emergency call. I'm now able to make regular phone calls without user interaction.

Is there any alternative to make emergency calls without user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems **123** is considered to be an emergency call number, and it seems to be restricted for ACTION_CALL if your phone number starts with any of the emergency call number.

Would you try a real number, or add the country code, e.g. "+34123123" and try again?

Comment: I do want to call an emergency number, but the problem occurs with regular numbers as well (tried call my contacts and the behavior is the same). Tx!

Comment: have you tried adding country code? it could be because the number in your contacts starts with number which is emergency number in another country

Comment: Moreover, calling emergency number requires another permission, which is only available to system apps.

Comment: I guess you're right... Now I'm able to start a phone call to my contacts but not to emergenty numbers. :/

Comment: I think you should consider this question closed and start a new question, instead of keep modifying your question...